# Java Frame can't close When using certain input method

Tags: java, swing, awt

Below is 2 simple java ui application, I found if the current IME is google pinyin When I click the right-upper close button of this Frame in Windows 7 and Windows XP OS, **the frame can be closed but the EDT thread doesn't terminate**.

the google pinyin IME download address is http://dl.google.com/pinyin/v2/GooglePinyinInstaller.exe.

And recently I found this situation also occurs when using Baidu Pinyin IME(another chinese input method). Diffrently, it occurs only when using swing, **randomly(the EDT thread can't terminate for a period of time, and become normal later)**.

I've read a article blaming the same problem similar to me long ago, and the author didn't come out with a solution too. I thought this is a bug in Google IME.

**I know most people view this question may not be Chinese and may be unable to install these 2 IME and try my samples, but it's just too ridiculous for me, how can these two things have relations??? do anybody have some idea to explain it based on your knowledge? I'll appreciate very much!**

```
    // AWT  
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Frame frame = new Frame("test");
            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                    frame.dispose();
                }
            });
            frame.setSize(400, 400);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Below is Swing

```
    // Swing
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("swing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(400, 400);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

As @MadProgrammer mentioned. I changed my code, using System.exit(0) in AWT and frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) in swing, the result is **I can't close the frame**, when I click the close button, nothing happens.

Comment: There are any number of possible reasons that the JVM might not terminate are the window is closed. It's possible there are other non-daemon threads still running for example. You could try adding System.exit to see if that forces it to terminate

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You should try using an exit listener, for example:

```
this.addWindowListener(new MyExitListener());
```

And the exit listener class:

```
public class MyExitListener extends WindowAdapter {

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This is what I usually do, and it always works.